# Бикубическая интерполяция поверхности

Tags: c++, интерполяция

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с проблемой интерполирования поверхности кубическим сплайном, изрыл весь интернет, но кроме банального интерполирования в квадрате [0,1]x[[0,1] ничего не нашел, а мне нужно интерполировать значение внутри произвольной области(неважно, по 16 точкам или по 4 с указанием всех производных и тд), привожу пример:
берем точки, удовлетворяющие уравнению эллиптического параболоида: x={100..102}, y = {100..102}

x = 100, y = 100, f(x,y) = 1805.56

x = 100, y = 101, f(x,y) = 1816.72

x = 100, y = 102, f(x,y) = 1828

x = 101, y = 100, f(x,y) = 1830.68

x = 101, y = 101, f(x,y) = 1841.85

x = 101, y = 102, f(x,y) = 1853.12

x = 102, y = 100, f(x,y) = 1856.06

x = 102, y = 101, f(x,y) = 1867.22

x = 102, y = 102, f(x,y) = 1878.5

Как мне теперь посчитать значение в точке {101.5, 101.5}?
Я читал статью на википедии, но там ничего не сказано про то, как это работает на произвольных точках, вне квадрата [0,1]x[0,1]

Хорошая реализация, которая работает на единичном квадрте и использует последовательную интерполяцию тут

```
double cubicInterpolate (double p[4], double x) {
    return p[1] + 0.5 * x*(p[2] - p[0] + x*(2.0*p[0] - 5.0*p[1] + 4.0*p[2] - 
p[3] + x*(3.0*(p[1] - p[2]) + p[3] - p[0])));
}

double bicubicInterpolate (double p[4][4], double x, double y) {
    double arr[4];
    arr[0] = cubicInterpolate(p[0], y);
    arr[1] = cubicInterpolate(p[1], y);
    arr[2] = cubicInterpolate(p[2], y);
    arr[3] = cubicInterpolate(p[3], y);
    return cubicInterpolate(arr, x);
}
```

Comment: http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/bookcpdf/c3-6.pdf

Comment: В трех словах не расскажешь. Я пользовался книгой "Методы вычислительной математики". Марчук Г.И. -- М.: Наука, Гл. ред. физ-мат. литературы, 1980. Глава 3, разделы 3.1 "Интерполяция функций одного переменного" и 3.2 "Интерполяция функций двух и многих переменных" (стр. 137-150) достаточно детально описывают как алгоритмы интерполяции, так и аппроксимации на произвольной прямоугольной сетке.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого надо:

1. Вычесть из x и из y 100.
2. Результаты поделить на 2.
3. В точке с полученными координатами вычислить значение сплайна для единичного квадрата

Comment: а как потом после вычисления на единичном квадрате вернуться к немасштабированным координатам?

Comment: А зачем возвращаться, вот же они!

Comment: ну мы получим довольно маленькие значения, как если бы находились в основании эллипсоида, а на самом деле мы находимся далеко и z для этих точек - большое число

Comment: С какой стати? Значения, которые мы вычисляем, зависят от: 1) значений в опорных точках; 2) положения точки внутри обезразмеренного квадрата. Больше ни от чего.

Comment: Для простоты, если рассмотреть линейную интерполяцию на одномерном отрезке, то значение в любой точке внутри этого отрезка будет зависеть лишь от опорных значений в концах отрезка (конкретные величины, не сама формула) и того, во сколько раз эта точка ближе к одному концу отрезка, чем к другому, но совершенно не зависит от протяженности отрезка, положения на прямой в пространстве, изменения с течением времени, фазы Луны и чего бы то ни было еще. В случаях больших размерностей и порядков — точно так же.

Comment: а ведь в функции cubicInterpolate коэффициенты подобраны для единичного квадрата только, разве не нужно пересчитывать коэффициенты?

Comment: @user9582211 вам не придётся пересчитывать коэффициенты если вы сведёте задачу к единичному квадрату